# Avaya SIP Phones Auth code shown in different line for outgoing calls

Tags: sip, avaya

Please note that I'm not familiar with Avaya CM or SM,
I have the following scenario:
An outgoing call is made from a SIP phone to an external number using auth code
The details about this call are sent from avaya to an external system via FTP.

The result:
The call is split in two lines:

1. Outgoing call from SIP extension to mobile number
2. Incoming call from auth code to a trunk

Why is this happening?
Is possible to have the auth code shown in the same line as the outgoing call?
Is there a specific setting that needs to be made?

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question, and is off-topic here as written.